# NodeJs waterfall callback functionality is not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, async.js

I  am using `npm` `async waterfall` method to write a functionality. There I found a strange situation(May be, My awareness is low). My function is as follows. I create an array of events in the first function and pass it to the second function via the callback parameters. Then I capture that array in the second function and loop it. I want to manipulate several values of the array. After that I send it to the final function.

The `console.log` statement in final function is only outputting the initial state of array from first function and not the manipulations that I have done in second function. Any idea is highly appreciated.

```
var _async = require('async');
var criteria =  {};

_async.waterfall([
    function getSortedCalenderItems(callback){
        var events = []; // set of events are included inthis array
        callback(null, events)
    },

    function getUsers(events, callback) {  
            for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
                var event = events[i];
                var user = event.shared_user;

                // manipulate user
                var newUser = {
                    'id' : '<id>',
                    'name' : 'New name'
                };

                event.shared_user = newUser;
                events[i-1] = event;

                if(i === (events.length)) {
                    callback(null, events)
                }
            }

    }
],function(err, events){
        console.log(events); // this shows the initial state of the array. Not the manipulated events array.
        return;
});
```

Comment: My awareness is *low*

Comment: you are not manipulating anything in your code, you just created a newUser and thats it. May be you forgot to add it to your list.

Comment: Yeah. You are correct. I have missed it. Please check the updated code now.

Comment: events[i-1] ? i is already starting from zero. Also you don't have to put back the event in events array.

Comment: and in the first iteration you are calling the callback parameter of second function this means your for loop will run just once for i = 0. Since you have written a blocking for loop you can move the callback invocation after the for loop.

Comment: @Sikorski Your answer is correct. Thank you for highlighted my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example;

```
var _async = require('async');
var criteria = {};

_async.waterfall([
    function (callback) {
        var events = [// set of events are included inthis array
            {
                name: "event1",
                shared_user : "halil"
            }, {
                name: "event1",
                shared_user : "halil"
            }
        ];
        callback(null, events);
    },
    function (events, callback) {
        console.log(events)
        for (var i = 0; i < events.length; i++) {
            var event = events[i];
            var user = event.shared_user;

            // manipulate user
            user = {
                'id': '<id>',
                'name': 'New name'
            };

            if (i === (events.length - 1)) {
                callback({}, events)
            }
        }
    }
], function (err, events) {
    console.log(err, events);
});
```